# how to delete repeated successive rows SQL

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, gaps-and-islands

i have history table with many rows T1, i need information from 3 rows so i have new table T2, and i want copy this information from T1 to T2.
but i have duplicate data ,so how copy right ?
some duplicate rows i need and some not .only if on column D i have same data like rows before i don't need info from this row
example:
i have table looks like this -
T1:

> Id B   D
>
> 1 8   10
>
> 2  8   3
>
> 3 8   3
>
> 4 8   10

i need this rows only -
T2:

> Id B   D
>
> 1  8   10
>
> 2  8   3
>
> 4  8   10

Comment: we could not copy needed duplicate rows separately.only thing is we can neglect whole dup rows

Comment: [`gaps-and-islands`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) (grouping successive rows) meets [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) (keeping one row from a group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare with the previous row data, if match then do not include it by where condition

```
;WITH data AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS Sequence FROM [Table]
)
SELECT Id, B, D 
FROM data d 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM data 
        WHERE Sequence + 1 = d.Sequence 
            AND B = d.B 
            AND D = d.D
    )
```

Comment: Eric tnx for your comment,exactly what i need

Comment: (upped) very pretty sql

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t2
select Id ,B ,D
(select * from t2
except
select d* from t1) t3
```